# Virtualhost configuration not manage correctly requests

Tags: apache, rest, xampp, virtualhost

I have the following Virtualhost config in httlp-vhosts.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName rest.budgettracker.loc
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/budget-develop/budget-develop/api/public"
    ErrorLog "logs/rest.budgettracker.loc-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/rest.budgettracker.loc-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName dev.budgettracker.loc
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/budget-develop/budget-develop"
    ErrorLog "logs/budgettracker.loc-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/budgettracker.loc-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

When I enter dev.budgettrackerpro.com in the browser it goes to the rest.budgettrackerpro.loc virtualhost container.

If I remove the Virtualhost container for the rest request it directs correctly to the correct html/javascript code. Obviously I need the rest call to make it work correctly. I have researched this until I am blue in the face, what am I doing wrong? Please help

Answer (score 0):

You are asking for dev.budgettrackerpro.**com**.  Your configuration is for dev.budgettrackerpro.**loc**.

What happens is:

- Apache sees that your request is on port 80 (http://...)
- It checks which `VirtualHost` are configured to take traffic from port 80.
- Here it finds 2.  1) rest.budgettracker.loc 2) dev.budgettracker.loc
- Since the domain you asked (the **.com**) does not match either 1) or 2), Apache assumes that the VirtualHost it should use is the first one it found.
- Apache when finding multiple VirtualHost or finding none that match uses the first one in the file (top to bottom).

To solve this:

- Request http://dev.budgettracker.loc
- Modify your `VirtualHost` to accept traffic form `.com` as well, like so:

  ```
  <VirtualHost *:80>
      ServerName dev.budgettracker.loc
      ServerAlias dev.budgettracker.com
      DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/budget-develop/budget-develop"
      ErrorLog "logs/budgettracker.loc-error.log"
      CustomLog "logs/budgettracker.loc-access.log" common
  </VirtualHost>
  ```

Notice the new line, `ServerAlias dev.budgettracker.com`.  You can have multiple `ServerAlias` in a `VirtualHost`, but only one `ServerName`.